# React count time from component mount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In React / Javascript, how can one count time from when the component mounted? I wish to stay on a page a minimum time of 0,8 seconds. **So when component mounts, I wish to start a timer, that calculates whether the 0,8 seconds have passed. When I'm about to leave the page, I want to check whether that time has passed, and if not, then wait for the remain time, and then leave the page.** How could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React has multiple life-cycle events which one of them is [`componentDidMount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount).

> `componentDidMount()` is invoked immediately after a component is
>   mounted. Initialization that requires DOM nodes should go here. If you
>   need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to
>   instantiate the network request. Setting state in this method will
>   trigger a re-rendering.

**Example**

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.mountTime = (new Date).getTime();
}

onSomeActionThatTriggersUnmount() {
  const currentTime = (new Date).getTime();
  if(currentTime >= (this.mountTime + 800)) {
    // proceed with the unmount
  } else {
    // not enough time yet
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm more interested in the counting part. I was going to do it in componentDidMount anyways. I'm sure there is some nice solution to the counting part.

Comment: @VilleMiekk-oja updated answer with an example but I must say, 800 milliseconds is really quick.